# Deleting a child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So first, this web-app is one of my first web-apps using react, and I have done it using JavaScript and C# .net core.

What I want to do is, on click of a Button i want to creat a component, that appears on screen.
And so far that part is working well.

```
import FusePageSimple from '@fuse/core/FusePageSimple';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import React, {ParentComponent, useEffect, useRef,useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import LeftSideBar from './components/SideBarComp';
import RightSideComp from './components/RightSideComp';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import { tokensToRegExp } from 'path-to-regexp';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    layoutRoot: {}
}));

function Dashboard(props) {
const [compCount, setCompCount] = useState(0);
const [component, setComponent] = useState('');

const eventhandler = data => {
    if(data.eliminar === 1){
    setComponent(component.filter((item) => item.props.RowNum !== data.RowNum));
    }
};

const classes = useStyles(props);
const pageLayout = useRef(null);


const onAddChild = () => {
    setCompCount(compCount + 1);    
}
useEffect(() => {
    const compArry = [...component];
    if(compCount > 0 ){
        compArry.push(<RightSideComp key={compCount} RowNum={compCount} onChange={eventhandler}/>)
    }
    setComponent(compArry);
}, [compCount]);

return (
    <FusePageSimple
        classes={{
            root: classes.layoutRoot
        }}
        header={
            <div className="flex flex-col flex-1">
                <div className="flex items-center p-24 px-12">
                    <Hidden lgUp>
                        <IconButton
                            onClick={ev => pageLayout.current.toggleLeftSidebar()}
                            aria-label="open left sidebar"
                        >
                            <Icon>menu</Icon>
                        </IconButton>
                    </Hidden>
                    <div className="flex-1 lg:px-12">
                        <h4>Header</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        contentToolbar={
            <div className="px-24">
                <h4>Content Toolbar</h4>
            </div>
        }
        content={
            <div className="p-24">
                <h4>Content</h4>
                <br />
                {component}
            </div>
        }
        leftSidebarHeader={
            <div className="p-24">
                <h4>Sidebar Header</h4>
            </div>
        }
        leftSidebarContent={
            <div className="p-24">
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary"
                onClick={ev => onAddChild()}>
                    Novo
                </Button>
                {/* <Button variant="contained" color="primary">Copiar</Button> */}
                <br />
                <LeftSideBar />
            </div>
        }
        innerScroll
        ref={pageLayout}
    />
);
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Thats the code of the parent.
So by clicking the button "Novo"(Means "New" in english) I call the onAddChild(), I add To the compCount and after with the UseEffect I add the child component. I pass 2 props to that Child RowNum, the number of components that I am creating, and an event that is trigger on state change.

```
import React,{ useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
root: {
    '& .MuiTextField-root': {
        margin: theme.spacing(2),
        width: '25ch'
    }
}
}));
function RightSideComp(props) {
const classes = useStyles();
const [component, setComponent] = useState({
    dataInicio: (!(props.datastate)  ? '' : props.datastate.dataInicio),
    dataFim: (!(props.datastate)  ? '' : props.datastate.dataFim),
    descricao: (!(props.datastate) ? '' : props.datastate.descricao),
    RowNum: props.RowNum,
    eliminar: 0,
    copiar: 0
});

console.log(component);
const handleChangeInput = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setComponent(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        [name]: value
    }));
};
const handleChangeButtonCopiar = event => {
    setComponent(preState => ({ ...preState, copiar: 1 }));
};
const handleChangeButtonEliminar = event => {
    setComponent(preState => ({ ...preState, eliminar: 1 }));
};
useEffect(() => {
    props.onChange(component);
}, [component]);






return (
    <div>
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <TextField
                id="dataInicio"
                label="Data Inicio"
                name="dataInicio"
                type="datetime-local"
                className={classes.textField}
                value={component.dataInicio}
                onChange={ev => handleChangeInput(ev)}
                InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true
                }}
            />
            <TextField
                id="dataFim"
                name="dataFim"
                label="Data do Fim"
                type="datetime-local"
                className={classes.textField}
                value={component.dataFim}
                onChange={ev => handleChangeInput(ev)}
                InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true
                }}
            />
            <TextField
                id="outlined-multiline-flexible"
                label="Multiline"
                name="descricao"
                multiline
                rowsMax={5}
                value={component.descricao}
                onChange={ev => handleChangeInput(ev)}
                variant="outlined"
            />
            <div>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={ev => handleChangeButtonCopiar(ev)}>
                    Copiar
                </Button>
                <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={ev => handleChangeButtonEliminar(ev)}>
                    Eliminar
                </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Divider />
    </div>
);
}

export default React.memo(RightSideComp);
```

and thats my child component.
So my error is when I change the eliminar("delete" in english) that component gets deleted. And with the code I have, if it is the last row it deletes fine but, if it is one from the middle it delets that one and all  the others that are below the one I clicked. I tried with slice and didnt work well too. I am missing something, but what?

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use 'useRef'

```
const refsList = React.useRef([]);
```

then when you create something

```
 compArry.push(<RightSideComp ref={refsList[compCount]} key={compCount} RowNum={compCount} onChange={eventhandler}/>)
```

now you can directly do anything you want with any elements based on this ref, eg. `refsList[0].current` will be the actual 1st element

```
refsList[0].current.remove()
```

Comment: so byt Using 'UseRef' gives you access to the component it self?

Comment: I can't acesse to it, the array is always at 0, do i need to populate it?